# Can users themselves set a description for their RichEmbed

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm developing a discord bot using `discord.js`. With my bot users have their own profiles. So they go **!profile @me** and their profiles come up. I'm wondering if there is a way for the user to use a command, say "**!setDescription I like Discord**". And when they use the command to view their profile "**!profile @me**" their profile embed will have the description they wrote, is this possible? And if so how could I incorporate this into my code? 
Thank you in advance for any help!

Answer (score 2):

You can store their description and then reuse it later:

When the user runs `!setDescription I like Discord` you save `I like Discord` in an object like this

```
//the user is stored as "message.author"
//the argument "I like Discord" is stored as "text"
var desc = {};
desc[message.author.id] = text; //desc -> {"id": "I like Discord"}
```

When the user runs `!profile @me` you use your `desc` object to get their description

```
//the user is stored as "message.author"
embed.setDescription(desc[message.author.id]);
```

Keep in mind that if you save the data into a variable, when you turn it off all the descriptions will be lost. To avoid that you can save the object into a JSON file or wherever you prefer.